# Disappearing users and answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Almost a week ago I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253289/applying-the-thue-siegel-theorem). One user, 'sunflower', gave me an incorrect answer (solves a simpler problem instead) - it happens sometimes. I decided to start a bounty, and it lead to an *excellent* answer from a user named 'Bullwinkle J. Moose'. There was also a good sub-discussion in the comments to his answer (involving me, him, and sunflower).

Today I checked my question and was surprised to see that 'sunflower' deleted his account and that 'Bullwinkle J. Moose' deleted his answer and his comments.

1. Is there any way for me to access "Bullwinkle J. Moose"'s deleted answer?
2. Is there something fishy going on here? (One user disappears, another deletes everything, both of the users are new).

Comment: Ofir, if you give me an email address, I can email you a pdf with the deleted answer + comments.

Comment: Thank you Andres, I sent you an email (found your mail in your blog). BTW, how do you have access to the deleted material?

Comment: 10K reputation. :-)

Answer (score 5):

User sunflower specifically asked for his account to be deleted for personal reasons.  This occasionally happens on all sites.

As for the other answer, I am not sure why the author deleted it.  Perhaps he felt there was an error, or perhaps he no longer wished to share it.

Comment: It's clear why the author deleted it: "I seriously wonder why I bothered posting this answer. On the one hand we have sunflower giving some rubbish argument using the full strength of Thue-Siegel-Roth incorrectly to prove something trivial, and then arguing about the (obvious) meaning of the question, and then we have people voting down this post and voting up the other one. I left MO because it was full of idiots who thought they knew something, at least on StackOverflow I thought it there would be modest people who are aware of their limitations and are interested in learning more. [ctd.]

Comment: [continuation] Apparently not." Note --- I have voted to undelete the answer.

Comment: For what it is worth, the "other" answer has been undeleted by the votes of three high rep users.